# How to prevent Win XP multiple File Copy to terminate if one file fails to copy

Tags: file, windows-xp, copy

When copying (or moving) multiple files using drag-and-drop in Windows XP, the copying process terminates if one files fails to copy. This is extremely annoying when copying a directory tree, and one has no real indication where exactly the process stopped, and what parts of the batch were not copied.

How can I prevent Windows from stopping the process upon one failure (and possibly get an indication for a problem)? It is easy to run a dir-compare program to see which files are missing after the fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is - you can't.

You're much better off using an alternative like XCopy or Robocopy from the command line if you want to reliably copy a lot of files and recover from errors along the way.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. I suspected so, but thought that there may be a registry hack or something so I give it a try. Anyway, is the 2nd part of your answer the "long answer"? If not, what is the long answer?

Comment: Yes.  Teh second part is the "long answer".  XCopy will do what you want, but Robocopy is much better.  I can't remember now, though, whether Robocopy is built into Windows XP, or not.  If it's not on your system you could probably find it on Microsoft downloads.